# PHP and mysql_query issue

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have this code in PHP:

```
$sql = '
SELECT t1.name, t2.code, COUNT(t2.code) as cnt 
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 
ON t2.code = t1.code2
WHERE (t2.input_date BETWEEN "2015-04-01" AND "2015-04-29") 
AND t2.serial = 5 
GROUP BY t2.code HAVING (t2.code>0)';

$Chartdata= mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
$arr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Chartdata)) {
    $arr[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

This code shows a blank page on my browser. I tried to delete the last one "AND" and "GROUP BY...", it shows 1 value.

Comment: You're selecting `t2.code` and aggregating that field inside the `count()`. This doesn't make much sense.

Comment: blank page = something blew up and you have all debug options turned off. if the query was working but returning nothing, the json_encode would at least have spit out an empty array, e.g. you'd see `[]`. Go into php.ini and turn on display_errors, error_reporting, etc.. and try again

Comment: @Phylogenesis Yup, I want to know how many times are the different "Codes"  in table 1

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Try just:

```
$sql = '
SELECT t1.name, t2.code, COUNT(*) as cnt 
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 
ON t2.code = t1.code2
WHERE (t2.input_date BETWEEN "2015-04-01" AND "2015-04-29") 
AND t2.serial = 5 
AND t2.code>0
GROUP BY t2.code';
```

Comment: Could you provide your data sample? or sqlfiddle would be perfect

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9793/6 I tried my code with phpMyAdmin and it worked but in php is not working

Comment: So what is wrong with your result then? show the real php code

Comment: This is the code that I am using: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/eaib-5fmp
When I use var_dump($arr). It shows the var type and content

Comment: Stop using mysql_ use mysqli or PDO!